# Pausing a Timer (Timers.Timer) VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, timer

I want to create a timer object that I can pause and resume.
The problem with the current `Timers.Timer` class is that when you call `Stop()` and then `Start()` it resets the interval and fires again after the whole interval has passed.

For example, If I have a `timerA` with `timerA.Interval = 5000`

Now if I do `timerA.Start()` and then after 3 seconds I called `timerA.Stop()` and then I wanted to wait for say 2 minutes.

After these 2 minutes I want to call `timerA.Start()` which should fire the Elapsed event after **2 seconds** (i.e. resume where I left off 2 minutes ago). But the problem is that `Timers.Timer.Start()` will always fire after 5 seconds again (starts the interval from 0 and not from 3 seconds).

Anyway, I created a VB.NET class that inherits from `Timers.Timer`, so can you please guys let me know if the above pause logic will stand with my code?

Code:

```
Imports System.Timers

Public Class TimerWithPause
Inherits Timers.Timer

Dim m_stopwatch As New Stopwatch
Dim m_interval As Integer 'original interval
Dim m_remainngtime As Integer 'to use when the Pause is requested
Dim m_state As TimerState = TimerState.Stopped

Public Sub New(Interval As Integer)
    m_interval = Interval
    MyBase.Interval = Interval
End Sub

Public Overloads Property Interval As Integer
    Get
        Return m_interval
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_interval = value
        MyBase.Interval = m_interval
    End Set
End Property

ReadOnly Property CurrentState As TimerState
    Get
        Return m_state
    End Get
End Property

Public Overloads Sub Start(startSate As StartStatus)
    MyBase.Interval = m_interval
    Select Case startSate
        Case StartStatus.StartNew
            StartNew()
        Case StartStatus.ResumeTimer
            'if current state is paused then resume
            If m_state = TimerState.Paused Then
                m_state = TimerState.Running
                m_stopwatch.Start()
                If m_remainngtime > 0 Then
                    MyBase.Interval = m_remainngtime
                End If
                MyBase.Start()
            ElseIf m_state = TimerState.Stopped Then 'else if the timer is stopped then start new
                StartNew()
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

Public Overloads Sub [Stop](stopState As StopStatus)
    Select Case stopState
        Case StopStatus.StopTimer
            m_state = TimerState.Stopped
            m_stopwatch.Reset()
            MyBase.Stop()
        Case StopStatus.PauseTimer
            m_state = TimerState.Paused
            m_stopwatch.Stop()
            MyBase.Stop()
            m_remainngtime = m_interval - m_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub TimerWithPause_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles Me.Elapsed
    StartNew() 'if the timer fires then it starts new cycle (because pauses happen in a middle of a running cycle)
End Sub

Private Sub StartNew()
    m_remainngtime = 0
    MyBase.Interval = m_interval
    m_state = TimerState.Running
    m_stopwatch.Restart()
    MyBase.Start()
End Sub

Enum StartStatus
    StartNew = 1
    ResumeTimer = 2
End Enum

Enum StopStatus
    PauseTimer = 1
    StopTimer = 3
End Enum

Enum TimerState
    Running = 1
    Stopped = 2
    Paused = 3
End Enum

End Class
```

And I use it this way:

```
Dim WithEvents tmr As New TimerWithPause(8000)
Private Sub RadButton10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton10.Click
    Select Case tmr.CurrentState
        Case TimerWithPause.TimerState.Running
            tmr.Stop(TimerWithPause.StopStatus.PauseTimer)
        Case TimerWithPause.TimerState.Stopped
            tmr.Start(TimerWithPause.StartStatus.StartNew)
        Case TimerWithPause.TimerState.Paused
            tmr.Start(TimerWithPause.StartStatus.ResumeTimer)
    End Select
End Sub
```

thank you guys in advance

Comment: ...so you want us to alpha test your code for you?  Not likely and not what the site is about.

Comment: I agree with @Plutonix. It's up to you to determine whether it works or not and then, if it doesn't, post here with a complete description of the problem. "Here's my code, does it work" doesn't fly here. That's not to say that it's not appropriate anywhere, but it's not here.

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com